# Swift MemoryLayout

Tags: ios, swift, memory, layout

I have a struct:

```
struct ShortResume {
    let age: Int32
    let hasVehicle: Bool
}
```

When I do `print(MemoryLayout<ShortResume>.size)`, it prints out 5, that is correct: Int32 occupies 4 bytes and Bool occupies 1 byte.

Then I change my struct to this:

```
struct ShortResume {
    let age: Int32?
    let hasVehicle: Bool
}
```

it prints out 6, that is also correct, because optional occupies 1 byte in memory.

However, when I change my struct to this:

```
struct ShortResume {
    let age: Int32?
    let hasVehicle: Bool?
}
```

it prints out 6 again, but it must be 7, because there are two optionals now.

Why? Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at

```
MemoryLayout<Bool?>.size
```

You'll see that it is actually 1. But

```
MemoryLayout<Int32?>.size
```

is 5 as expected.

You may know that `Optional` is an enum declared like this:

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)

    // ...
}
```

So the memory needed for a `T?` is the memory needed for `T`, plus one flag bit to store whether it is `none` or `some`. Therefore, one byte is theoretically more than necessary to store a `Bool?`.

And it turns out that Swift is actually really smart - in the current implementation, this flag can go in any unused place in the layout of `T`, which is why the flag and the value of the `Bool` are in the same byte.

These are some of my experiments:

```
struct A {
    let w: Bool
    let x: Int8
    let y: Int8
    let z: Int8
}

MemoryLayout<A?>.size // 4, that flag must be in the first byte

struct B {
    let w: Int8
    let x: Bool
    let y: Int8
    let z: Int8
}

MemoryLayout<B?>.size // 4, that flag must be in the second byte

struct C {
    let w: Int8
    let x: Int8
    let y: Bool
    let z: Int8
}

MemoryLayout<C?>.size // 4, that flag must be in the third byte

struct D {
    let w: Int8
    let x: Int8
    let y: Int8
    let z: Bool
}

MemoryLayout<D?>.size // 4, that flag must be in the last byte

struct E {
    let w: Int8
    let x: Int8
    let y: Int8
    let z: Int8
}

MemoryLayout<E?>.size // 5, that flag must be in the extra byte
```

Comment: But why one byte is enough to keep both Bool and optional, but not enough to keep both Int8 and optional as in your last example? Is Bool the only one value type that occupies the same size in memory whether it's optional or not?

Comment: @MaryLitv21 `Int8` by definition requires all 8 bit or 1 byte to store the value, so there is no way to put in anymore information than the integer itself in that byte, thus requiring 2 byte.

Comment: @MaryLitv21 On the other hand, you can have a enum that stores up to 255 or 2^8-1 cases, and occupy the same space with the optional, since it only need to add one extra case `.none` to the entire layout.

Comment: @MaryLitv21 please read the second half of my answer again and Ranoiaetap’s comments and tell me what you don’t understand about it. Remember that a `Bool` is just one bit, an eighth of  a byte. And to answer your second question, yes there are other types like this, the `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` types I declared are exactly like this.